# Python Pandas - Index' object has no attribute 'hour'

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a pandas dateframe and the following code works

```
df['hour'] = df.index.hour
df['c'] = df['hour'].apply(circadian)
```

but i was trying to reduce the need to make a 'hour' coloumn, using the following code

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: circadian(x.index.hour), axis=1)
```

but I get the error message

```
AttributeError: ("'Index' object has no attribute 'hour'", u'occurred at index 2015-09-25 01:00:00')
```

anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Convert the `DateTimeIndex` to `Series` and use `apply`.

```
df['c'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: circadian(x.hour))
```

**Approach 2:**

Use `axis=0` which computes along the row-index.

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: circadian(x.index.hour), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

***solution***
use the datetime accessor `dt`

```
df['c'] = df.index.to_series().dt.hour.apply(circadian)
```